# Как работает TaskScheduler?

Tags: c#, tpl

Использую код из [примера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8) с сайта майкрософт. Вот класс о котором пишут

> Он создает настраиваемый планировщик задач, ограничивающий количество потоков, используемых приложением.

```cs
public class LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler: TaskScheduler {
  // Indicates whether the current thread is processing work items.
  [ThreadStatic]
  private static bool _currentThreadIsProcessingItems;

  // The list of tasks to be executed 
  private readonly LinkedList < Task > _tasks = new LinkedList < Task > (); // protected by lock(_tasks)

  // The maximum concurrency level allowed by this scheduler. 
  private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;

  // Indicates whether the scheduler is currently processing work items. 
  private int _delegatesQueuedOrRunning = 0;

  // Creates a new instance with the specified degree of parallelism. 
  public LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(int maxDegreeOfParallelism) {
    if (maxDegreeOfParallelism < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxDegreeOfParallelism");
    _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
  }

  // Queues a task to the scheduler. 
  protected sealed override void QueueTask(Task task) {
    // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough 
    // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another. 
    lock(_tasks) {
      _tasks.AddLast(task);
      if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism) {
        ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
        NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
      }
    }
  }

  // Inform the ThreadPool that there's work to be executed for this scheduler. 
  private void NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork() {
    ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
      // Note that the current thread is now processing work items.
      // This is necessary to enable inlining of tasks into this thread.
      _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = true;
      try {
        // Process all available items in the queue.
        while (true) {
          Task item;
          lock(_tasks) {
            // When there are no more items to be processed,
            // note that we're done processing, and get out.
            if (_tasks.Count == 0) {
              --_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
              break;
            }

            // Get the next item from the queue
            item = _tasks.First.Value;
            _tasks.RemoveFirst();
          }

          // Execute the task we pulled out of the queue
          base.TryExecuteTask(item);
        }
      }
      // We're done processing items on the current thread
      finally {
        _currentThreadIsProcessingItems = false;
      }
    }, null);
  }

  // Attempts to execute the specified task on the current thread. 
  protected sealed override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) {
    // If this thread isn't already processing a task, we don't support inlining
    if (!_currentThreadIsProcessingItems) return false;

    // If the task was previously queued, remove it from the queue
    if (taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
      // Try to run the task. 
      if (TryDequeue(task))
        return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
      else
        return false;
    else
      return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
  }

  // Attempt to remove a previously scheduled task from the scheduler. 
  protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task) {
    lock(_tasks) return _tasks.Remove(task);
  }

  // Gets the maximum concurrency level supported by this scheduler. 
  public sealed override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel {
    get {
      return _maxDegreeOfParallelism;
    }
  }

  // Gets an enumerable of the tasks currently scheduled on this scheduler. 
  protected sealed override IEnumerable < Task > GetScheduledTasks() {
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try {
      Monitor.TryEnter(_tasks, ref lockTaken);
      if (lockTaken) return _tasks;
      else throw new NotSupportedException();
    } finally {
      if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(_tasks);
    }
  }
}
```

В `Main` я пишу

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
  // Create a scheduler that uses two threads. 
  LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(5);
  List < Task > tasks = new List < Task > ();
  // Create a TaskFactory and pass it our custom scheduler. 
  TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(lcts);
  CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  // Use our factory to run a set of tasks. 
  Object lockObj = new Object();
  int outputItem = 0;
  int count = 0;
  while (count < 100) {

    Task t = factory.StartNew(() => {
      lock(lockObj) 
      {
        count++;
      }
      Console.WriteLine(count);
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
  }
  // Wait for the tasks to complete before displaying a completion message.
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
  cts.Dispose();
  Console.WriteLine("\n\nSuccessful completion.");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вроде как должно создаться 100 тасков и они должны повысить `count` до 100 и вывести числа на экран, но каждый раз результат разный от 9к до 13к выполнений.
Как я понимаю класс `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` это настройка которую мы передаем в класс `TaskFactory` и этот класс контролирует выполнения тасков. В данном случае я передал число одновременно выполняющихся тасков `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(5)`, вроде как программа должна держать все время запущенными 5 тасков, но все работает не так как я думал.

Вопрос в том правильно ли я понял назначения класса `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`? Его можно использовать для ограничения одновременно выполняющихся Тасков?
Я пока практикуюсь на кошках, в дальнейшем мне нужно будет выполнять тысячи Тасков но при этом что бы были запущены только 50штук.

Comment: А в чем ваша задача? Чем вас класс Parallel не устроил или может ваш сценарий хорошо ляжет на DataFlow?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну я спрашивал у людей как мне выполнять много тасков в очереди и ограничивать количество запущенных тасков, мне посоветовали этот код.

Comment: ну а суть задачи то в чем?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну это код для примера, а вообще мне надо загружать задачи которые будут парсить гугл, и ограничить количество одновременно выполняющихся тасков.

Comment: первая же ссылка в гугле [Limit The Number Of C# Tasks That Run In Parallel](https://blog.danskingdom.com/limit-the-number-of-c-tasks-that-run-in-parallel/) - чем вам не подходит? и без танцев с шедулером.

Comment: вторая ссылка из гугла, все тот же семафор [How to limit the Maximum number of parallel tasks in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36564596/312041)

Comment: советы от кого то из MC [Multiple ways how to limit parallel tasks processing](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/fkaduk/multiple-ways-how-to-limit-parallel-tasks-processing) и ничего нет про шедулер, даже ссылка на [репу есть с готовым кодом](https://github.com/kadukf/blog.msdn/tree/master/.NET/ParalellizedTasks).

Comment: в общем, вот вам ключевые слова для гугла `c# task parallel limit`, там много всего. А шедулер, имхо, это уже перебор, он только усложнит вам жизнь. Какой смысл его брать, прикручивать ещё и пул потоков, если простой семафор сделает то же самое, но проще и легче?

Comment: Всем спасибо, ну я взял что мне посоветовали, и мне показалось что это простое решение, просто передать аргументом количество запущенных потоков и все будет работать